# How to implement "while loop" function to find total distance and time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a 3 part assignment that I understand what to do, just doing it is confusing. I am stuck on figuring out how to write this code for **Part B.** (I understand Part A).

A) Use a loop to generate 1000 random integers in the range 10 to 20 (inclusive). Find the average of your 1000 random integers.  It should be close to 15.

```
import random
from random import randrange

def main():
 numbers = [] 
  for count in range(1000):
    number = random.randrange(10,21)
    numbers.append(number)
  print(sum(numbers)/len(numbers))

main()
```

B) Assume that the race track is 2 miles long. Your horse can run at most 40 feet in one second, but for any given
second may run any number of feet between 4 and 40.
Your program should have a loop that calculates the horses position at the end of every second until the horse
crosses the finish line. Each second, generate a random integer and add it to the horses current position. **The output should be the number of seconds required to complete the race**.

So far I know what I should do (here is my outline), I just don't know how to code it:

I know that 1 mile is 5280 so 2 miles is 10560.

I know that the range for any given second is [4,41).

```
def race():
 #position variable
 #position variable
 #while loop condition
    #increment seconds
    #add random value to position
#return elapsed seconds
```

I can do Part C which asks to run 1000 races & avg seconds to finish race.

Answer (score 0):

You're on it towards the answer.  I won't solve it for you but here is how I would go after it.

Your while loop needs to check and see if you crossed the finish lines, so

```
while finished is False:
    if race_total_distance - distance_so_far <= 0:
        finished = True
        # record your race results
    else:
    # do your race calcs here and go again
```

Then for each second, you need to increment your time `+= 1` and add to your `distance_so_far` variable for this sections feet which you showed how to do already.

Answer (score 0):

While this feels  an awful lot like doing your homework for you, here you go.
If you encounter a problem like this again, try to "translate" your comments into code, one by one - you were almost done.

```
def race()
    goal = 10560 # 2 miles are 10560 feet
    current_position = 0 # position variable
    elapsed_seconds = 0 # time variable
    while current_position < goal: # while loop condition
        elapsed_seconds += 1 # increment seconds
        current_position += random.randrange(4,41) # add random value to position
    return relapsed_seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a for loop just track the `current_pos` and time

```
import random

lista = [random.randint(10, 20) for i in range(1000)]
avg = sum(lista)/len(lista)
track = 2 * 5280
current_pos = 0
seconds = 0
while current_pos <= track:
    current_pos += random.randint(4, 40)
    seconds += 1
print('{} seconds to finish the race'.format(seconds))
# 492 seconds to finish the race
```